# Connecting to EC2 via SSH with keypair

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to connect to EC2 via SSH with a key, but whenever I type the command `chmod 400 key.pair.pem`, I got this message:

> `chmod : cannot access ' kp.pem': no such file  or directory.`

In fact, the `kp.pem` has been downloaded and can be found in the `Download` directory in the Ubuntu system.

My question is what must I do (command to use) to enable `chmod 400` to locate the `key.pair` in the `Downloads` folder or any folder in the directory?

I have already tried the following:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
mv ~/Downloads/ec2private.pem ~/.ssh
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/ec2private.pem
```

Comment: You show at least three variations of what I believe is the same filename: `key.pair.pem`, `kp.pem` and `key.pair`. Also note that the `~/.ssh` directory must have `700` permissions (`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`). Changing it to `400` would make it impossible for you to access files in that directory.

Comment: And not only do you show different variations, `' kp.pem'` has a space in it. So quoting trouble might be the reason for it. BTW, you don't need to keep the filename secret. That said, typically you don't use a PEM, but put the public key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server (or set that up via AWS tools), while the private key is on the machine you want to ssh from, typically as `~/.ssh/id_XXX`, where XXX depends on the kind of key.